# Kendo Window positioning

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-window

I am using `bootstrap` template and `Kendo Window` and so far positioning of modal kendo windows wasn't too hard.
But now as I a use a different layout for a certain area, I find myself having problems with that matter.

following code is expected to create a centered (x-axis) modal kendo window:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("Window1")
  .Visible(false)
      .Position(builder => builder.Top(100))
      .Draggable()
      .Content(@<div class="kendoWindowContent"><p>Please wait...</p><div class="k-loading-image"></div></div>)
    .Width(1000)
      .Title("Title1")
      .Actions(actions => actions.Close())
      .Modal(true)
      .Resizable())
```

..and displaying via:

```
   var wnd = $("#ownerVoucherCreateWindow").data("kendoWindow");

        wnd.refresh({
            url: '@Url.Action("Voucher_Create", "OwnerVoucher")'
        });

        wnd.open();
```

The window is not beeing displayed in the middle of the x axis.

Are there any constraints in order to have the kendo window beeing centered.

Answer (score 1):

Window centering requires the usage of the [`center()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#methods-center) method. Since the Window content is loaded via Ajax, you need to center the widget in its [`refresh`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#events-refresh) event.

```
var wnd = $("#ownerVoucherCreateWindow").data("kendoWindow");
wnd.one("refresh", function(e) {
    e.sender.center();
});
wnd.refresh({
    url: '@Url.Action("Voucher_Create", "OwnerVoucher")'
});
wnd.open();
```

It is also possible to trigger centering in every refresh event, instead of [just once](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/events-and-methods#event-binding-after-initialization).

Another option is to set explicit [`width`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#configuration-width) and [`height`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#configuration-height). In this case you can center the Window at any time, because the widget dimensions will not change after changing (loading) the content.

Comment: Thanks for you're input! I don't want the window to be displayed centered in the y axis but only the x axis (I use an offset of +200 to top (y=0) so I cannot use the center() method for my purpose.

Comment: another thing is: event with explicit set dimensions and centering the window is not beeing displayed in the very center.

Comment: you got a typo here: wnd.one("refresh", function(e) {
    e.sender.center();
});

Answer (score 1):

ok I guess I was just lucky that all my kendo windows happened to be displayed centered although specifying an explicit offset to top like described.
I assumed, that the window would automatically center on y-axis when having only an x-axis position set.
As it seems this is not the case. I don't really know why this has been working in the past.
Anyway, I figured out a way to center the window depending on the browsers' viewport and window width:

just in case anybodes cares...

```
 function displayWindowCenteredOnYAxis(kendoWindow) {

        var windowOptions = kendoWindow.options;

        var pos = kendoWindow.wrapper.position();

        var viewPortWidth = $(window).width();
        var wndWidth = windowOptions.width;

        pos.left = viewPortWidth / 2 - wndWidth/2;

        kendoWindow.wrapper.css({
            left: pos.left
        });

        kendoWindow.open();
 }
```

Usage:

```
    var wnd = $("#id").data("kendoWindow");

    wnd.refresh({
        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")'
    });

    displayWindowCenteredOnYAxis(wnd);
```